# React Native for Android ScrollView height doesn't adjust when elements are removed

Tags: react-native

What happens is when the view renders and after that some elements are removed, the ScrollView height doesn't change, so there is extra white space at the bottom. It fixes itself when something is tapped or on scroll.

I have tried to do "scrollTo" on "onContentSizeChange", but this looks very choppy, because it already jumps up when elements are removed, so doing scroll after that is noticeable.

Has anyone ran into the same issue? Is there a possible solution for this? Any input would be greatly appreciated.